# can and how can I change returned value to a constant?

Tags: c#, enums, constants

when I call this method:

```cs
[EnumMember]
PersonalDataChemicalSubstanceQuestionMD_1 = EnumsHelpers.GetWizID("PersonalDataChemicalSubstanceQuestionMD_1")
```

I get this error: "The expression being assigned to “” must be a constant".

this is my helper method:

```cs
private static int wizId = 0;

/// <summary>
/// Summary
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
public static int GetWizID(string pdq)
{
   var server = Properties.Settings.Default.ServerEnvironment;
   switch (server)
   {
       case "DEV":
           switch (pdq)
           {
               case "PersonalDataChemicalSubstanceQuestionMD_1":
                   wizId = 3728;
                   break;
           }
           break;
   }
   return wizId;
}
```

Can the value returned be converted to a constant?  How can this be fixed?

Comment: you cannot, enums need to be compile time constants

Comment: A `constant` is a constant value, that is a not changing value. A value returned by a function may differ -> no const. `"myvalue"` or `5` may be assigned to a constant.